# SQL - LEFT JOIN multiple conditions - priority

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables with a structure similar with this:

> table: user
>
> fields: id, active_office_address_id (this can be 0)
>
> table: user_address
>
> fields: id, user_id, type (home, office)

A user can have a "home" address (not mandatory) and multiple "office" addresses. I have a join to get a user address, but I want that if the user have a "home" address to get that address, not "office" address.

So, how can I get "home" address if exists, and only if that not exists to get "office" address. (In reality the query is much more complicated and the join is done on 4-5 tables)

```
SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN user_address ON (user.id = address.user_id AND 
(user_address.type = "home" OR user.active_office_address_id = user_address.id))
group by user.id
```

Comment: The coalesce function will help you, assuming mysql supports it.

Comment: @morandi3 . . . Do you want all office addresses or just one?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `COALESCE()` and join to your address table twice:

```
  SELECT user.id
       ,COALESCE(home.address, office.address) AS Address
  FROM user 
  LEFT JOIN user_address AS home
     ON user.id = home.user_id 
       AND home.type = "home"
  LEFT JOIN user_address AS office
     ON user.active_office_address_id = office.user_id 
  GROUP BY user.id
```

Comment: Might need to be office.id? Not entirely clear, but the important bit is the `COALESCE()` and joining twice, since the address data is presumably normalized.

Comment: What are home.address and office.address? The id?

Comment: They would be the actual address field you're trying to return.

Answer (score 3):

Two left joins and a case statement will give you the address id you want.

```
SELECT user.*,CASE WHEN home_addr.id IS NOT NULL THEN home_addr.id ELSE ofc_addr.id END AS addr_id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_address AS home_addr
  ON (user.id = home_addr.user_id AND home_addr.type = 'home')
LEFT JOIN user_address AS ofc_addr
  ON (user.active_office_address_id = ofc_addr.id)
```

You could feed this back in as a sub-select for a particular user:

```
SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN user_address
WHERE user.id = ?
AND user_address.user_id = user.id
AND user_address.id IN
    (SELECT CASE WHEN home_addr.id IS NOT NULL THEN home_addr.id ELSE ofc_addr.id END AS addr_id
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN user_address AS home_addr
      ON (user.id = home_addr.user_id AND home_addr.type = 'home')
    LEFT JOIN user_address AS ofc_addr
      ON (user.active_office_address_id = ofc_addr.id)
    WHERE user.id = ?)
```

This assumes that only one home address exists per user.

Comment: Yes, only one home address exists per user.

Answer (score 0):

At least in SQL Server, not sure about MySql, you can use a `case` statement in the order by clause, for example:

```
order by user.id, case user_address.type when 'home' then 1 else 2 end, --additional ordering clauses here
```